# Clarification on derivatives in non-inertial frames of reference

Tags: reference-frames, rotational-dynamics

Let there be an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{A}$ and let $S$ be an inertial set of axes $\hat{i},\hat{j},\hat{k}$ and $S'$ a rotating system with the same origin as $S$ and basis vectors $\hat{i'},\hat{j'},\hat{k'}$ . Now I've seen that the relation between the derivatives of $\mathbf{A}$ in the two frames is given by:
$$\left(\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dt}\right)_S=\left(\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dt}\right)_{S'}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathbf{A}$$
What I don't understand is whether the $\mathbf{A}$ in the $\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathbf{A}$ term is in the coordinates of $S$ or in those of $S'$. Also, if the $\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathbf{A}$ is in the coordinates of $S'$ and so is the $\left(\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dt}\right)_{S'}$ term, I get an equation of the form $\left(\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dt}\right)_S=\dot{a_1}\hat{i}+\dot{a_2}\hat{j}+\dot{a_3}\hat{k}=a
_1'\hat{i'}+a_2'\hat{j'}+a_3'\hat{k'}$ where $a_i'=\left(\dot{a_i} \right)_{S'}+(\boldsymbol{ \omega} \times \mathbf{A})_i$. My question is, how do I express $\left(\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dt}\right)_S$ in the basis of $S$. If the rotation of $S'$ is about one of the principal axes then the transformation between the sets of axes is pretty straightforward and I understand it well enough. However, what about an arbitrary axis? If for example $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ creates an angle $\alpha$ with the $\hat{k'}$ axis? How can I find the rotation matrix for such a case?

Answer (score 5):

Like anything else with vectors in mechanics, all quantities have to be expressed in the *same* coordinate system in order to be able to do standard vector calculus things like add or scale vectors.

So the answer is that $\boldsymbol{A}$ can be in either coordinate system, as long as $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is also in the same orientation. The above equation is not a transformation of coordinates, but rather a statement on how to combine the local change of a vector $\left( \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} A \right)_{S'}$ with the general motion of a body/frame $\boldsymbol{\omega}$.

What the notation $\left( \cdot \right)_S$ and $\left( \cdot \right)_{S'}$ means is not the resolution of vectors on different coordinate systems, but rather **changes as seen by such frame**.

A vector fixed on the body will seem unchanging by somebody riding on the body and hence $\left( \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{A} \right)_{S'} = \boldsymbol{0}$, but the motion of the body will make the vector change as seen by someone on an inertial frame.

In the more general case, the expression below is a statement about kinematics, and not a transformation of coordinates.

$$ \underbrace{ \left( \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{A} \right)}_{\text{as seen by S}} = \underbrace{ \left( \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{A} \right)}_{\text{as seen by S'}} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{A} \tag{1}$$

In the above scenario $\boldsymbol{A}$ is expressed in the same coordinate orientation as $\boldsymbol{\omega}$, and $S$ and $S'$ *both have the same orientation* at some instant, but one is rotating $S'$ and the other isn't.

---

If you want to do the above, but consider the changing rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}(t)$ between the two vectors *expressed at different orientations*, where ' indicates rotated frame, and no ' indicates word coordinate frame.

$$ \boldsymbol{A}(t) = \mathbf{R}(t)\,\boldsymbol{A}'(t) \tag{2}$$

We can omit the $(t)$ since everything can change with time. Then from geometry we know that the columns of the rotation matrix change with the following rule: $\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\mathbf{R} = \boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathbf{R}$. So the differentiation of the above (using the derivative product rule) is

$$ \begin{aligned}\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\boldsymbol{A} & =\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\mathbf{R}\right)\boldsymbol{A}'+\mathbf{R}\,\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\boldsymbol{A}'\right)\\
 & =\left(\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathbf{R}\right)\boldsymbol{A}'+\mathbf{R}\,\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\boldsymbol{A}'\right)\\
 & =\mathbf{R}\,\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\boldsymbol{A}'\right)+\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\left(\mathbf{R}\boldsymbol{A}'\right)\\
 & =\mathbf{R}\,\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\boldsymbol{A}'\right)+\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\boldsymbol{A}
\end{aligned} \tag{3}$$

which is the form of the rotating derivative you are inquiring about, that considers the rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ in addition to the motion $\boldsymbol{\omega}$.